# Take programmatic screenshots of websites including live webcam-images

Tags: video, web, screenshot, webcam, live

I want to take screenshots of websites by their URL, but the goal is to capture the live webcams that are broadcasted on these websites. When i programmatically take screenshots the area where the webcam is shown is a black square. How can I make sure that the screenshot also includes the area where the webcam is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible (in your case, and it's also typical), video playback is routed through video hardware overlay which is not read back when you take a screenshot. So you get blackness instead of real webcam image.

The easiest solution in your case is to open a video player application on the background (which can be the same application with one of the webcams). It is okay to leave it on pause, it just have to have a video playback session in progress to lock video overlay. Video overlays are typically a limited resource in amount of 1 (one) per hardware item, so locking it would force other players to fall back to screenshot-friendly method of displaying video.

From there your webcam screenshots will be fine. No coding is necessary, but you can certainly do similar programmatically as well.